# Set a value of an object in javascript from a function without calling the function

Tags: javascript

I know I'm over complicating this but I'm curious.

So I have a function:

```
 var setSize = function(selectedSize){
    var split = {
      size: val.sizes.split(','),
      tcin: val.tcin.split(','),
      idx: function(){
        return this.size.indexOf(selectedSize);
      }
    };
    console.log(split.idx)
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>choose a size</p>
<div onClick="setSize('small')>small</div>
```

QUESTION:

**Is this possible** to have split.idx to have a value of say `0` not a value of function.

Comment: Just replace the function with a zero? Did you try it.

Comment: Sorry I can reframe the question.  it's more like selectedSize will come from the user. so split.idx will change in value.

Comment: `idx : (selectedSize ? function(){
                return this.size.indexOf(selectedSize);
              } : 0 )`

Comment: Do you mean `split.idx()` *return* a value of `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a modern browser, you can use a getter for the `idx` property so that it becomes a calculated property.

The programmmer would access it as `split.idx`, but the value would still be calculated by a function.

Details on getters here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

```
 var setSize = function(selectedSize){
    var split = {
      size: val.sizes.split(','),
      tcin: val.tcin.split(','),
      get idx() {
        return this.size.indexOf(selectedSize);
      }
    };
    console.log(split.idx)
   }
```